# How can I check if a string has +, -, or . (decimal) in the first character?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am writing a program that will determine if a double literal is 4 characters, and print it out on the screen. I believe I did the part right where I will check to see if there are exactly 4 characters. I am stuck on how to check if a +, - or . is the first character. With my 
`str.charAt(0) == "+" || "-" || "."` I am receiving an Incompatible operand error.

```
public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str;

    System.out.println("Please enter a valid (4 character) double literal consisting of these numbers and symbols: '+', '-', '.', (decimal point), and '0' through '9'");

    str = stdIn.nextLine();
    int length = str.length();

    // the next if statement will determine if there are exactly 4 characters \\
    if ( length == 4 ) { 

        // the next if statement checks for a +, -, or . (decimal) in the first character \\
        if ( str.charAt(0) == "+" || "-" || ".") {

        }
    }


    else {  

        System.out.println ("Please restart the program and enter in a valid 4 character double literal.");

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if ("+-.".indexOf(str.charAt(0)) >= 0) {`

Comment: `str.charAt(0) == '+' || str.charAt(0) == '-' || str.charAt(0) == '.'`

Comment: This is not COBOL; you can't do "shortcut" Boolean operations like `x == a || b || c`. You have to write out each comparison in full: `x == a || x == b || x == c`

Comment: `String#startsWith`

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
switch ( str.charAt(0) ) {
  case '+': case '-': case '.':
    <do something>
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this   `if ( str.charAt(0) == "+" || "-" || ".") {`

with

```
`if ( str.charAt(0) == '+' || str.charAt(0)=='-' || str.charAt(0)=='.') {
```

Comment: Still invalid Java syntax, since you can't say `a == 1 || 2 || 3`

Comment: obviously -----

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> ```
>     if ( str.charAt(0) == "+" || "-" || ".") {
> ```

... does not make sense.  The operands of the `||` operator need to be `boolean`s.  The expression `str.charAt(0) == "+"` evaluates to a `boolean`, but the two strings standing by themselves do not.

There are numerous ways to solve this problem, and which one makes the most sense for you depends on context.  However, *one* way to go about it uses the fact that string literals are `String`s like any other, on which you can invoke methods.  Such as `indexOf()`:

```
if ("+-.".indexOf(str.charAt(0)) >= 0) {
    // starts with +, -, or .
}
```

Comment: You didn't address the other issue with the code, i.e. the comparing of a `char` to a string literal, not a character literal.